# Making a CoreImage filter than sums all row pixels, similar to CIRowAverage?

Tags: cocoa, core-image, cifilter

I'm currently running code on the CPU that sums columns and rows of an **grey scale** NSImage (i.e. only 1 samplePerPixel). I thought I would try to move the code to the GPU (if possible). I found a CoreImage filters [CIRowAverage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRowAverage) and [CIColumnAverage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColumnAverage) which seem similar.

In the Apple Docs on writing [custom Core Image filters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html) they state,

> Keep in mind that your code can’t accumulate knowledge from pixel to pixel. A good strategy when writing your code is to move as much invariant calculation as possible from the actual kernel and place it in the Objective-C portion of the filter.

This hints that maybe one cannot make a summation of pixels using a filter kernel. If so, how do the above function manage to get an average of a region?

So my question is, what the best way to implemented summing row or columns of a image to get the total value of the pixels. Should I stick to the CPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Core Image filters perform this averaging through a series of reductions. A former engineer on the team describes how this was done for the CIAreaAverage filter within [this GPU Gems chapter](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch26.html) (under section 26.2.2 "Finding the Centroid").

I talk about a similar averaging by reduction in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168072/fragment-shader-average-luminosity/12169560#12169560). I needed this capability on iOS, so I wrote a fragment shader that reduced the image by a factor of four in both horizontal and vertical dimensions, sampling between pixels in order to average sixteen pixels into one at each step. Once the image was reduced to a small enough size, the remaining pixels were read out and averaged to produce a single final value.

This kind of reduction is still very fast to perform on the GPU, and I was able to extract an average color from a 640x480 video frame in ~6 ms on an iPhone 4. You'll of course have a lot more horsepower to play with on a Mac.

You could take a similar approach to this by reducing in only one direction or the other at each step. If you are interested in obtaining a sum of the pixel values, you'll need to watch out for precision limits in the pixel formats used on the GPU. By default, RGBA color values are stored as 8-bit values, but OpenGL (ES) extensions on certain GPUs can give you the ability to render into 16-bit or even 32-bit floating point textures, which extends your dynamic range. I'm not sure, but I believe that Core Image lets you use 32-bit float components on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Moving to the GPU is tricker that I thought. My purpose is processing scientific data where the brightness of the pixels have a meaning (arrival event of photons). Keeping everything linear is very important, and I'm not happy to offload this sort of work to the GPU unless I can be sure I understand exactly how it works. Unfortunately the CoreImage plugins seem to convert everything to RGB, and sometime add peculiarly offsets and scaling factors to the images (true for CIGaussianBlur). Maybe I will get around to this when polish is required! I need to learn OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

FYI on the CIAreaAverage filter—it's coded like this:

```
    CGRect inputExtent = [self.inputImage extent];
CIVector *extent = [CIVector vectorWithX:inputExtent.origin.x
                                       Y:inputExtent.origin.y
                                       Z:inputExtent.size.width
                                       W:inputExtent.size.height];
CIImage* inputAverage = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAreaAverage" keysAndValues:@"inputImage", self.inputImage, @"inputExtent", extent, nil].outputImage;

//CIImage* inputAverage = [self.inputImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIAreaMinimum" withInputParameters:@{@"inputImage" : inputImage, @"inputExtent" : extent}];
EAGLContext *myEAGLContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
NSDictionary *options = @{ kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null] };
CIContext *myContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:myEAGLContext options:options];

size_t rowBytes = 32 ; // ARGB has 4 components
uint8_t byteBuffer[rowBytes]; // Buffer to render into

[myContext render:inputAverage toBitmap:byteBuffer rowBytes:rowBytes bounds:[inputAverage extent] format:kCIFormatRGBA8 colorSpace:nil];

const uint8_t* pixel = &byteBuffer[0];
float red   = pixel[0] / 255.0;
float green = pixel[1] / 255.0;
float blue  = pixel[2] / 255.0;
NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f\n", red, green, blue);
```

Your output should look something like this:

```
2015-05-23 15:58:20.935 CIFunHouse[2400:489913] 0.752941, 0.858824, 0.890196
2015-05-23 15:58:20.981 CIFunHouse[2400:489913] 0.752941, 0.858824, 0.890196
```